Why do i get access denied error when I try to implement RabbitMQ?
Im working on a code, where there are some files coming from a folder, and i want to implement RabbitMQ, so it takes the files, transform them according to my code, and then send it to my db. When  I wrote the program first, i did it without using RabbitMQ, and it worked perfectly, but now that I try to do the same with RabbitMQ, I get the following error message:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
HResult=0x80070005
Message=Access to the path 'C:\\ExampleFolder' is denied.
Source=System.Private.CoreLib
StackTrace:
    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable\`1 unixCreateMode)
    at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable\`1 unixCreateMode)
    at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable\`1 unixCreateMode)
    at System.IO.StreamReader.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
    at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding)
    at Program.SendMessage(String rabbitMqHost, String queueName) in C:\\C# kódok\\MSG5_Process_C#\\MSG5_Process_C#\\Program.cs:line 39
    at Program.Main() in C:\\C# kódok\\MSG5_Process_C#\\MSG5_Process_C#\\Program.cs:line 20

Im the admin of my computer(However its a notebook of the company I work for, but we checked the rights and I should be able to do anything with the folder)

When I tried to access the file through a simple C# code, it worked perfectly.

I tried to run Visual Studio in Sysadmin mode.


Here you can see the relevant part of the code:
    static void SendMessage(string rabbitMqHost, string queueName)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = rabbitMqHost };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                                 durable: true,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            string msg5FilePath = "C:\\msg5files";
            string message = File.ReadAllText(msg5FilePath);


It isn't necessarily a filesystem permissions issue - but it could be a file-locking (i.e. file-already-in-use) issue - are you sure C:\msg5files isn't locked by another process?

Yes, i tried to do it from multiple approaches, i moved the files in different folders on my desktop. The C:\msg5files is directly created for testing functions, and this code is the only one that should use it.

Use cacls on the file in an elevated command-prompt and tell us what the output is. Also run ProcessExplorer and use its  Find Handles command for that file and tell us what you see.

BUILTIN\Felhasználók:(ID)C
BUILTIN\Rendszergazdák:(ID)F
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(ID)F
NT AUTHORITY\Hitelesített felhasználók:(ID)C

Your Windows (internal) user-name contains non-ASCII characters - methinks that's going to cause problems. I suggest you try again, but use a Windows user-account with only [a-z]-ranged chars and see if it repros.
